# Issues using "-f" flag in CQLSH to run a query.cql file

Tags: database, cassandra, cql, cqlsh, cassandra-2.1

I'm using cqlsh to add data to Cassandra with the BATCH query and I can load the data with a query using the "-e" flag but not from a file using the "-f" flag. I think that's because the file is local and Cassandra is remote. Details below:

This is a sample of my query (there are more rows to insert, obviously):

```
BEGIN BATCH;
INSERT INTO keyspace.table (id, field1) VALUES ('1','value1');
INSERT INTO keyspace.table (id, field1) VALUES ('2','value2');
APPLY BATCH;
```

If I enter the query via the "-e" flag then it works no problem:

```
>cqlsh -e "BEGIN BATCH; INSERT INTO keyspace.table (id, field1) VALUES ('1','value1'); INSERT INTO keyspace.table (id, field1) VALUES ('2','value2'); APPLY BATCH;" -u username -p password -k keyspace 99.99.99.99
```

But if I save the query to a text file (query.cql) and call as below, I get the following output:

```
>cqlsh -f query.cql -u username -p password -k keyspace 99.99.99.99

Using 3 child processes

Starting copy of keyspace.table with columns ['id', 'field1'].
Processed: 0 rows; Rate:       0 rows/s; Avg. rate:       0 rows/s
0 rows imported from 0 files in 0.076 seconds (0 skipped).
```

Cassandra obviously accepts the command but doesn't read the file, I'm guessing that's because the Cassandra is located on a remote server and the file is located locally. The Cassandra instance I'm using is a managed service with other users, so I don't have access to it to copy files into folders.

How do I run this query on a remote instance of Cassandra where I only have CLI access?

I want to be able to use another tool to build the query.cql file and have a batch job run the command with the "-f" flag but I can't work out how I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're executing a **local** cqlsh client so it should be able to access your local `query.cql` file.

Try to remove the `BEGIN BATCH` and `APPLY BATCH` and just let the 2 `INSERT` statements in the `query.cql` and retry again.

One other solution to insert data *quickly* is to provide a **csv** file and use the **COPY** command inside `cqlsh`. Read this blog post: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/new-features-in-cqlsh-copy

Scripting insert by generating one `cqlsh -e '...'` per line is feasible but it will be horribly slow

Comment: Thanks doanduyhai. Removing the `BEGIN BATCH` and `APPLY BATCH` statements fixed the problem. I'll take a look at the **COPY** command, do you know if there is a specific format required for the **csv** file?

Comment: cqlsh COPY command is very flexible with regards to CSV formatting. Just type `help COPY` inside **cqlsh** to list all available options